# Combining file and directory selection options

Tags: python, function, scripting, command-line-arguments

I would like to combine the functionality of two arguments to one. Currently -f may be used to specify a single file or wild-card, -d may specify a directory. I would like -f to handle its currently functionality or a directory.

Here's the current options statements:

```
parser.add_option('-d', '--directory',
        action='store', dest='directory',
        default=None, help='specify directory')
parser.add_option('-f', '--file',
        action='store', dest='filename',
        default=None, help='specify file or wildcard')
if len(sys.argv) == 1:
    parser.print_help()
    sys.exit()
(options, args) = parser.parse_args()
```

Here is the logic in the functionality, can these be combined?

```
filenames_or_wildcards = []

# remove next line if you do not want allow to run the script without the -f -d
# option, but with arguments
filenames_or_wildcards = args # take all filenames passed in the command line

# if -f was specified add them (in current working directory)
if options.filename is not None:
    filenames_or_wildcards.append(options.filename)

# if -d was specified or nothing at all add files from dir
if options.directory is not None:
    filenames_or_wildcards.append( os.path.join(options.directory, "*") )

# Now expand all wildcards
# glob.glob transforms a filename or a wildcard in a list of all matches
# a non existing filename will be 'dropped'
all_files = []
for filename_or_wildcard in filenames_or_wildcards:
    all_files.extend( glob.glob(filename_or_wildcard) )
```

Comment: "can these be combined"?  Are you asking how to combine the various lines of code -- lines which are all different?

Comment: @S.Lott: I'm asking how the filename and directory directives may be combined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a list of wildcards, directories and files to this function. However, your shell will expand your wildcards if you do not put them between quotes in the command line.

```
import os
import glob

def combine(arguments):
    all_files = []
    for arg in arguments:
        if '*' in arg or '?' in arg:
            # contains a wildcard character
            all_files.extend(glob.glob(arg))
        elif os.path.isdir(arg):
            # is a dictionary
            all_files.extend(glob.glob(os.path.join(arg, '*')))
        elif os.path.exists(arg):
            # is a file
            all_files.append(arg)
        else:
            # invalid?
            print '%s invalid' % arg
    return all_files
```

Comment: currently I do not have to use quotes with wildcards, is that a limitation of the function or wildcards?

Comment: @Astron - my function accepts a list/tuple of options from the user, so you can call it with `combine(options.filename)`.
In shell, if you do `python yourScript.py *.txt`, it won't receive the string `*.txt`, but the list of files in your current directory, such as `a.txt b.txt c.txt`.